# How to extract bitmap from spritesheet in Win32 C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, bitmap

I'm trying to load individual cards from a spritesheet of cards based on suit and rank but I'm unsure of how to construct a new Bitmap object from cutting out Rectangle coordinates in the source image. I'm using `<windows.h>` currently and trying to find a simple way to accomplish this. I'm looking for something like this:

`HBITMAP* twoOfHearts = CutOutFromImage(sourceImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 76, 116));`

From source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ9Od.gif

Comment: Are you using gdiplus? If so, `Bitmap::Clone` is probably what you want.

Comment: Nope just Win32 =( No extra graphics libraries

Comment: Create a new bitmap with `CreateCompatibleBitmap` or `CreateDIBitmap` or similar, select it into a DC, and blit the appropriate section from the source with `BitBlt`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function I played with the other week for more-or-less this same task. In my case, I wanted to return a HBRUSH that could be used with FillRect. In that instance, we still need to create a bitmap of the area of interest, before then going on to create a brush from it.

In your case, just return the `dstBmp` instead. `spriteSheet` is a global that has had a 256x256 spritesheet loaded. I've hardcoded the size of my sprites to 16x16, you'd need to change that to something like 81x117.

Here's some code that grabs a copy of the required area and some more that uses these 'stamps' to draw a level map. That said - there are all kinds of problems with this approach. Speed is one, excessive work is another one that impacts on the first. Finally, scrolling a window drawn like this produces artefacts.

```
// grabs a 16x16px section from the spriteSheet HBITMAP
HBRUSH getSpriteBrush(int col, int row)
{
    HDC memDC, dstDC, curDC;
    HBITMAP oldMemBmp, oldDstBmp, dstBmp;
    curDC = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);

    memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    dstDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

    dstBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(curDC, 16, 16);
    int xOfs, yOfs;
    xOfs = 16 * col;
    yOfs = 16 * row;

    oldMemBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, spriteSheet);
    oldDstBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(dstDC, dstBmp);
    BitBlt(dstDC,0,0,16,16, memDC, xOfs,yOfs, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(memDC, oldMemBmp);
    SelectObject(dstDC, oldDstBmp);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, curDC);
    DeleteDC(memDC);
    DeleteDC(dstDC);

    HBRUSH result;
    result = CreatePatternBrush(dstBmp);
    DeleteObject(dstBmp);
    return result;
}

void drawCompoundSprite(int x, int y, HDC paintDC, char *tileIndexes, int numCols, int numRows)
{
    int mapCol, mapRow;
    HBRUSH curSprite;
    RECT curDstRect;

    for (mapRow=0; mapRow<numRows; mapRow++)
    {
        for (mapCol=0; mapCol<numCols; mapCol++)
        {
            int curSpriteIndex = tileIndexes[mapRow*numCols + mapCol];
            int spriteX, spriteY;

            spriteX = curSpriteIndex % 16;
            spriteY = curSpriteIndex / 16;

            curDstRect.left = x + 16*mapCol;
            curDstRect.top = y + 16 * mapRow;
            curDstRect.right = curDstRect.left + 16;
            curDstRect.bottom = curDstRect.top + 16;
            curSprite = getSpriteBrush(spriteX, spriteY);
            FillRect(paintDC, &curDstRect, curSprite);
            DeleteObject(curSprite);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The latter function has since been replaced with the following:

```
void drawCompoundSpriteFast(int x, int y, HDC paintDC, unsigned char *tileIndexes, int numCols, int numRows, pMapInternalData mData)
{

    int mapCol, mapRow;
    HBRUSH curSprite;
    RECT curDstRect;
    HDC memDC;
    HBITMAP oldBmp;
    memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    oldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, mData->spriteSheet);

    for (mapRow=0; mapRow<numRows; mapRow++)
    {
        for (mapCol=0; mapCol<numCols; mapCol++)
        {
            int curSpriteIndex = tileIndexes[mapRow*numCols + mapCol];
            int spriteX, spriteY;

            spriteX = curSpriteIndex % mData->tileWidth;
            spriteY = curSpriteIndex / mData->tileHeight


// Draw sprite as-is
//            BitBlt(paintDC, x+16*mapCol, y+16*mapRow,
//                   mData->tileWidth, mData->tileHeight,
//                   memDC,
//                   spriteX * 16, spriteY*16,
//                   SRCCOPY);

// Draw sprite with magenta rgb(255,0,255) areas treated as transparent (empty)
            TransparentBlt(
                           paintDC,
                           x+mData->tileWidth*mapCol, y+mData->tileHeight*mapRow,
                           mData->tileWidth, mData->tileHeight,

                           memDC,
                           spriteX * mData->tileWidth, spriteY*mData->tileHeight,
                           mData->tileWidth, mData->tileHeight,
                           RGB(255,0,255)
                           );
        }
    }
    SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
    DeleteObject(memDC);
}
```